# Remove row with certain column length?

Tags: sorting, awk, sed, string-length

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
A : 1
Boy : 3
Ahoy! : 7
more : 8
```

I have to remove rows whose length is less than or equal to 3 alphabets long. The output should look like this:

```
Ahoy! : 7
more : 8
```

Thanks

Comment: something like `awk 'length($1)>3'` ?

Comment: you might use something like `awk -F: '$2 >3' yourfile`, here I assume that the number after the colon is the value, you want to filter on. And that you want to filter for less than 4, because the Boy line is missing from your example output.

Comment: When you say `less than 3 alphabets long` do you mean `less than 3 characters long` or `contains less than 3 alphabetic characters` or  `contains less than 3 contiguous alphabetic characters` or something else? Do you mean across the whole line or just in the first field (before the `:`) or something else?  Put some more effort into providing sample input/output that really demonstrate the problem you're trying to solve - right now there's far too many possible correlations between your input and output for it to help much.

Comment: "Boy" is 3 "alphabets" long,  not less than 3, so why do you remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is a little bit unspecific and (due to comm(ent|un)ication) there evolved some possible solutions depending on how I interpreted the question.

My 1<sup>st</sup> script `filter.awk`:

```
$3 <= 3 { next }
{ print $0 }
```

considers only the 3<sup>rd</sup> column (using standard white space separation). Thus, the number after the colon is compared with constant `3`.

Your test input `filter.txt`:

```
A : 1
Boy : 3
Ahoy! : 7
more : 8
```

Test:

```
$ awk -f filter.awk filter.txt
Ahoy! : 7
more : 8

$
```

Ed Morton pointed out that it can be done even shorter:

```
$3 > 3
```

This was new for me also. (May be, I was confused by lex which works the opposite way: In lex/flex, everything unmatched is echoed.)

A more robust approach would be to use the colon (`:`) as column separator (or like it is named in awk: field separator). Changing the field separator can be achieved by assigning the built-in variable `FS`. This can be done using the command line argument `-F` or by assignment in a special `BEGIN` rule which is always performed at start. (I prefer the letter to make the scripts "self-contained".)

Thus, `filter2.awk` (i.e. `filter.awk` V2.0):

```
BEGIN { FS = ":" }
$2 <= 3 { next }
{ print $0 }
```

or considering what I've learnt today:

```
BEGIN { FS = ":" }
$2 > 3
```

Test:

```
$ awk -f filter2.awk filter.txt
Ahoy! : 7
more : 8

$
```

Another interpretation of the OP might be to consider the number of consecutive letters in the first column of every line. To achieve this, some of the built-in functions come into play:

1. `gensub()` a powerful replacement function which is unfortunately only in GNU awk available
2. `length()` which returns the length of a string (or the number of elements in an array)

For this I use an extended test input `filter2.txt`:

```
A : 1
Boy : 3
Ahoy! : 7
more : 8
Hello World : 0
Hello! World. : 0
Hi World : 0
```

`filter3.awk` (i.e. `filter.awk` V3.0):

```
length(gensub(/(^[A-Za-z]+).*$/, "\\1", 1, $1)) > 3
```

Test:

```
$ awk -f filter3.awk filter2.txt
Ahoy! : 7
more : 8
Hello World : 0
Hello! World. : 0

$
```

As the field separator is unchanged in this case, the 1<sup>st</sup> field consists of the characters until 1<sup>st</sup> white space. The pattern `(^[A-Za-z]+)` catches all letters at begin of text and stores them into 1<sup>st</sup> internal buffer. The `.*$` matched the rest until end of text. This whole text is replaced by buffer `\1`. (Consider the escaped backslash in `"\\1"`.) This works fine on my bash in cygwin because I once defined `LANG=C` in my bash-initialization (after having trouble with the German locale). Ed Morton (again) pointed out that using `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `[A-Za-z]` should be more robust.

If you have a non-GNU awk, then `gensub()` is not available. (A few weeks ago, another guru (one with a **k** in his reputation) teached me that there are rather no other awks than gawks out there in the world. Checking this, I realized that even the awk in our companies Windows VS build chain is actually a gawk. However, since I learnt this I stumbled multiple times over the fact that my answers were not well-excepted because I didn't consider that the solution was explicitly (or implicitly) required for non-GNU awk...)

So here is my 4<sup>th</sup> version for non-GNU awk `filter4.awk`:

```
{
  text = $1
  gsub(/[^[:alpha:]].*$/, "", text)
  if (length(text) > 3) { print $0 }
}
```

Test:

```
$ awk -f filter4.awk filter2.txt
Ahoy! : 7
more : 8
Hello World : 0
Hello! World. : 0

$
```

For `gsub()`, I reverted the logic of reg-ex replacement: Everything from first non-alpha character until end of text is replaced by the empty string. (AFAIK, there even does not exist something like enumerated buffers in `gsub()`.)

The assignment to temporary variable `text` is necessary because `gsub()` modifies the contents of its 3<sup>rd</sup> argument. If I had provided `$1` directly (as I did before fixing it) its contents would be changed which in turn had changed also the contents of `$0`.

Comment: `$3 <= 3 { next } { print $0 }` is literally just `$3>3` in entirety but in any case I don't think that's what the OP is looking for at all.

Comment: wrt `gensub(/(^[A-Za-z]+).*$/, "\\1", "g", $1)` - 1) you should mention that's specific to gawk and newer mawks, 2) that character list is locale-dependent, use `[[:alpha:]]` instead, 3) you can't match `^` multiple times so the 3rd arg should be `1`, not `"g"`. I still have no idea if what that code implements is what the OP is looking for of course since she hasn't told us yet :-).